# Netbeans stalls at Opening Project - Recover from crash on Ubuntu?

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Netbeans under Ubuntu 14. Netbeans was not doing anything, so I killed the process. Then, I reopend it, but it stalls at Opening Project.

I believe I need to clean the cache directory. Is that correct? If yes, where is it located under Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the location of the 'cache' directory [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir). I have deleted the whole content and restarted Netbeans. It was a bit slow to reload the project, since it is a large project over a mount, but it worked.